# abandoned memory

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, modalviewcontroller, abandoned-memory

in my code :

```
    ABNewPersonViewController *c = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
    [c setNewPersonViewDelegate:self];
    [c setDisplayedPerson:newPerson];
    CFRelease(newPerson);


    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:c];
    [self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
```

some where it seams to be an abandoned memory, that I detect whit Instrument.
Any clue why?

Answer (score 0):

release c. It has been retained in nc

Comment: Ok, but I use ARC, so just do c=nil?

Answer (score 0):

try removing CFRelease, and make the UINavigationController as ivar. That's how ARC would know to keep the navigation controller in memory till the particular class is deallocated.

```
ABNewPersonViewController *personViewController = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
[personViewController setNewPersonViewDelegate:self];
[personViewController setDisplayedPerson:newPerson];

//this line is not required
//CFRelease(newPerson); 

//UINavigationController *personNavigationController; define nc as ivar in the .h file.
personNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:personViewController];
[self presentModalViewController:personNavigationController animated:YES];
```

And if you would like to follow some naming conventions from Apple, then readability of your code will be definitely great.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but it go even worse, abandoned memory grow even quicker. If I understand correctly all C function are not released whit ARC. Shouldn't I need to release newPerson?

Comment: Okay. It seemed to me that "newPerson" was an objective C class object. So I had asked you not to take care of releasing it since ARC would release it for you.And usually new should not be prefixed with variables. It confuses the static analyzer(new, init, alloc will tell the compiler about ownership of the object). Can you try this 2 things. 1) changing the variable name of newPerson variable. 2) Making an Objective C model to store that new person object(so that you wouldnt need to worry about CFRelease..)

Comment: newPerson is declared for calling addressBook, so that I could add new contact in addressBook. The whole library is C classes even on Apple tutorial. The problem is that in every tutorial program automatically add contact, but I want to open addressBook and show the user what he will add to his contact. I guess that problem is in some of the controllers, because object remain in memory are view connected. Previous answer was something retaining one of the controller but I dont know how to handle it. Do you have some hint?